# Maven Errors in STS while working on Demo Spring Roo Project

Tags: maven, m2eclipse, spring-roo

I was trying to work on the Spring Roo Demo project @ www.springsource.org/roo/guide?w=beginning and I am using Spring Roo Shell in the STS IDE.

However, as I go through the various steps of demo project, I see that the pom.xml is created / updated by Roo. However, the dependencies are NOT getting downloaded.

I am not a maven expert, however, I tried the below steps to resolve the issues.

1. Made sure Maven is NOT working in offline mode - 
   my looking into preferences -> maven -> offline mode not checked.
   I was also kind of sure about this because, maven was downloading other jars from repositories
2. I tried manually downloading the junit-4.8.2.jar and log4j-1.2.16.jar from the Maven Central repository to my local and tried manually installing the files using the commands

   ```
   mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=junit -DartifactId=junit -Dversion=4.8.2 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=C:/Users/Satya/Downloads/junit-4.8.2.jar
   mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=log4j -DartifactId=log4j -Dversion=1.2.16 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=C:/Users/Satya/Downloads/log4j-1.2.16.jar
   ```

Maven told me the installation was successful on my windows command prompt, however, I did not see anything getting reflected in my STS IDE.

I tried, using the m2eclipse menu and "updating dependencies", "clean" etc.. to no use.

[Maven Build Errors in STS IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjX1S.png)

[Compilation Errors that I am getting in STS because of the Maven Build Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mh3aw.png)

I am not sure what else I should be doing to resolve this and continue with the Spring Roo work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem! :)

I was trying to achieve everything with one single download of Spring Source Tool Suite.
Looks like I needed to add - MAVEN_HOME, JAVA_HOME environmental variables and the bin directories of both MAVEN and JAVA to the path, which was the reason none of the jars were getting downloaded automatically and I was seeing all compilation issues.

True that I was dumb, but at least it shows that I should not have ignored the most basics of Java, Maven! :-)

Comment: Cheers and all the best with Roo! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the following in Roo console:

```
perform eclipse
```

Comment: I am already in Spring Tool Suite (STS) and per Spring Roo documentation, if I had used STS right from the beginning to create the project, I should not be using the "perform eclipse" command - not sure if I should still go ahead :) but am gonna try!.